# How can I use char/String as an aswer for yes or no on math question(n1>2, n1<n2)

Tags: java

Im struggling with that code.
how can I use string with yes/no on that question: n1>n2, n1<n2.
the operators also need to change.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class s {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int n1 = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int n2 = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

        int max = Math.max(n1, n2);

        System.out.println("What is higher: "+n1+" or "+n2+" ");
        int result = s.nextInt();

        if(result==max)
            System.out.println("Well done");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *exactly* do you need? What do you not understand?

Comment: The questions: "is n1>n2" "is n1<n2".                                                                                     The answer should be as: yes,Yes or no,NO.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a way to not use a lot of IF’S by splitting the two possible cases and not having many repeated coding lines.
By avoiding this situation, I started creating: random numbers, the random operator “>” or “<” and a boolean variable which value depends on the answer of the user.
Then I defined a variable called “reality” that will provide the correct answer, referring to which number is bigger or smaller than the other.
Finally, the program verifies if the answer of the user is the same to the reality printing the expected answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
        int bol_op= (int) Math.random()>0.5?1:0;
        String operator= bol_op==1?">":"<";
        int num1=(int) (Math.random()*100+1);
        int num2=(int) (Math.random()*222+1);
        String str_num1=num1+"";
        String str_num2=num2+"";
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("********Logic Program**********");
        System.out.println("Question: "+str_num1+operator+str_num2);
        System.out.print("Answer (yes/no): ");
        String answer =sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        boolean value=false;
        if(answer.equals("yes")){
            value=true;
        }
        boolean reality=num1>num2?true:false;
        if(bol_op==0){
            reality=num1<num2?true:false;
        }
        if(reality==value){
            System.out.println("Well done");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong answer");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The operators remain the same as <. how can I change it to < and >. Also instead of yes or no I want to put either yes or Yes and no or No.

Comment: Please share any relevant code as text [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).